# 'DataFrame' object is not callable : datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, python-datetime

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date = pd.read_csv("D:\Python_program\DATE.csv")
date.head(5)

date[pd.to_datetime(date['sr_date']) > pd.Timestamp(date('08-08-2021'))]

date
```

Then I get the error messave:

```
error:- TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B14OI.png)

Comment: `date = pd.read_csv...` you are clobbering your import by naming the frame the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Randy mentions in the comment, you're over-riding the name `date` from the import line:

```py
from datetime import date
```

when you read in your dataframe:

```py
date = pd.read_csv("D:\Python_program\DATE.csv")
```

Now `date` no longer refers to `datetime.date` but to the dataframe.
(**EDIT**) Furthermore, correct usage of `pd.Timestamp` [from the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) would look like this, so you don't need the `date` function:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:\Python_program\DATE.csv")
df[pd.to_datetime(df['sr_date']) > pd.Timestamp(2021, 8, 8)]
```

Comment: problem not solve ,,  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-46392c7589ae> in <module>
----> 1 df[pd.to_datetime(df['sr_date']) > pd.Timestamp(date('08-08-2021'))]

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: I edited the answer to help with this `TypeError`. If that does fix things, please accept the answer! I can't be sure it works, because you haven't shared what the contents of `df['sr_date']` is.